# Restarting MultipeerConnectivity Service Advertiser with different discoveryInfo

Tags: swift, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to restart my `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` with different `discoveryInfo` but the old `discoveryInfo` seems to remain despite completely replacing the advertiser instance with a new one with the new info. If I change it multiple times, `ServiceBrowsers` tend to see the discovery information of the previously active `ServiceAdvertiser` rather than the currently a active one.

```
let oldDiscoveryInfo = ["playerName": "Dave"]
self.serviceAdvertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: PeerID.shared.myPeerID,
                                                  discoveryInfo: discoveryInfo,
                                                  serviceType: "SpinHost")
self.serviceAdvertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()


//Now change the discovery info
serviceAdvertiser.stopAdvertisingPeer()
let newDiscoveryInfo = ["playerName": "Steve"]
self.serviceAdvertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: PeerID.shared.myPeerID,
                                                  discoveryInfo: newDiscoveryInfo,
                                                  serviceType: "SpinHost")
self.serviceAdvertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()
```

I've tried adding a delay to staring up the new ServiceAdvertiser but it still doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: If it is an option for you, you could renew your peer ID. This seems to work for me.

Comment: Ooo! Very interesting! Thanks for letting me know. I'll give that a go but that sounds really promising! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @BartWesselink you solved my issue. Thanks, really appreciate your help!